# remove-variable and pipeline - null-valued expression?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove some variables in my PowerShell script like so:

```
#create example com object
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#do something with COM object, close COM object etc

#clear variable
get-variable | where-object { $_.Value -ne $null -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.GetType() } | remove-variable
```

But it returns:
**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.**

on the get-variable.... line?  However, when I test that line like so:

```
get-variable | where-object { $_.Value -ne $null -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.GetType() } | Select -Property Name
```

It returns the correct data?  I get the same behaviour with:

```
get-variable | where-object { $_.Value -ne $null -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.GetType() } | ForEach-Object { remove-variable -Name $_.Name  }
```

I can't figure out why remove-variable doesn't work?  The remove-variable cmdlet accepts 'Name' in the pipeline by 'PropertyName' so i think that looks ok to me?

**UPDATED**

Interestingly, the full error is multiple occurrences of this (interesting because the line should only return 3 results but there are 48 of these error messages):

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:31
+ ... re-object { $_.Value -ne $null -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.Ge ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

**ALSO**

This works:

```
$vars = get-variable | where-object { $_.Value -ne $null -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.GetType() } | Select-object -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($var in $vars) {
   remove-variable -Name $var
}
```

But this doesn't?:

```
get-variable | where-object { $_.Value -ne $null -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.GetType() } | foreach { remove-variable -Name $_.Name }
```

Comment: Please post the full error :)

Comment: $null should always be on the left hand side of the operator

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in the end by adding more null checks in the where-object part of the pipeline (thanks @ScottHeath):

```
get-variable | where-object { $null -ne $_ -And $null -ne $_.Value -And $null -ne $Excel -And $_.Value.ToString() -eq $Excel.GetType().ToString() } | foreach { Remove-Variable -Name $_.Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Com objects need to be released from memory with:

```
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

After that, remove the variable itself with

```
$Excel = $null
Remove-Variable -Name Excel
```

`Remove-Variable` also has an `-Include` parameter where you can specify an array of variable names. Wildcards are also permitted there.

Comment: Thanks @Theo.  You read my mind.  I've just been reading this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317109/office-application-does-not-exit-after-automation-from-visual-studio-n and at the end it mentions using FinalReleaseComObject instead of ReleaseComObject....

Comment: @Captain_Planet I didn't know that one, but [FinalReleaseComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) apparently is useful as alternative to looping `ReleaseComObject` and since we're not loopinh here.. Anyway, glad to know.